# How do I get the width of a div in a window after it got rendered by react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the size of a div (css width: 100%) and set the zoom factor of a component according to the div's size. The problem is on first run of the App, the div doesn't exist in the DOM yet, since return has not created it. So I tried to put it in a useEffect to check if it gets created. However for some reason this doesn't work, when I put the `querySelector` into a constant because I thought the constant would be recreated once the component renders again because useEffect should trigger a re-render. When I put it directly into the deps, I get a warning about exhaustive deps.

```
React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

How do I properly extract the querySelector into a variable to have the app react to it being rendered?

```
const App = () => {
    const querySelector = document.querySelector(".area-main"); //doesn't exist on 1st render but should be recreated on second render?
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(querySelector && querySelector.clientWidth > 1000){
            setZoom(1.5);
        }
        console.log(querySelector); // null
    }, [querySelector]); //chould change on re-render from null to element but doesn't trigger
    // the following works but complains about complex dependency tells me to extract (how?)
    //}, [document.querySelector(".area-main")]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(zoom); //prints out 1 once
    }, [zoom]);

    return(
        <div className=".area-main">
            <Component zoom={zoom} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

According to the comment, I tried using layout effect but that doesn't change

```
const querySelector = document.querySelector(".canvas-main");

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(querySelector); //prints out null once
}, [querySelector]);
```

Comment: I wonder if `useLayoutEffect` would help?

Comment: Maybe, I am not experenced with that

Comment: Actually don’t use querySelector at all. Use a “useRef” instead.

Comment: I tried it with layoutEffect. Doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: like how? const querySelector = useRef(document.querySelector(".canvas-main")); and then querySelector.current in useEffect deps? Edit: Ok the answer explained it

Comment: No. Pass the ref to the element. Try not to use querySelector at all. It does not work well with react (in most cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a reference to the div element, you'll want to use a react ref. Then you can access that ref in a `useLayoutEffect` and do what you need to do. `useLayoutEffect` is similar to `useEffect`, except if you set state it will cause a *synchronous* rerender, and that way you won't have a flicker on the screen as you reposition things.

```
const App () => {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const divRef = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current.clientWidth > 1000) {
      setZoom(1.5)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className=".area-main">
      <Component zoom={zoom} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more information on refs, [see this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Thanks, just for clarification, console.log(divRef); works in layoutEffect but it doesn't tell me to put difRef into useLayoutEffect dependencies. Why is this?

Comment: It doesn't tell you to put it in the dependencies, because it wouldn't change anything. `divRef` is the same object every single time the component renders. `divRef.current` does change (react-dom will put the element in there once the element has been created), but you wouldn't put that in the dependencies either, because the component doesn't rerender when divRef.current changes.